# Hibernate not creating Database in PostgreSql Using Spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying code first approach to create database using Spring Boot and Hibernate.

But, I am not able to do that yet.

Please suggest how can I Solve this.

Here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.inventory</groupId>
<artifactId>publisherinventory</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>PublisherInventory</name>
<description>project for publishers inventory</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Here is application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/BookInventory
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Here is my Enity

```
package com.inventory.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class BookGroup{

@Column(name="groupName")
public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

@Id
@Column(name="groupId", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue
public int getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}

private String groupName;
private int groupId;
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
package com.inventory.controllers;

import com.inventory.model.BookGroup;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import javax.validation.Valid;


@Controller
public class BookGroupController {

BookGroup aBookGroup = new BookGroup();

@RequestMapping(value = "/bookGroupEntry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String bookGroupEntryForm(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("bookGroup",aBookGroup); // "bookGroup" ->BookGroup (Class Name)
    return "bookGroupEntry";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/showBookGroups", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String bookGroupSubmit(@ModelAttribute @Valid BookGroup aBookGroup, Model model){

    return "showBookGroups";
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema Maybe not an exact duplicate, but you should read it and turn over every stone.

Comment: @Tareq did you get same error? exception?

Comment: For starters you are mixing hibernate 5.1 and 5.2 jars. And hibernate 5.2 isn't supported by the version of Spring Boot and Spring you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue. The problem was with wrong set of properties.
Have a look here: [Spring Boot + Hibernate + Postgres - not creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053390/spring-boot-hibernate-postgres-not-creating-tables/38084714#38084714)