# Generate MySql database with springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, spring-boot

I want to generate MySQL database with springboot project. 
I create a maven project, this is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>ma.mahmoud.springboot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringBootApps</name>
<description>First project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- BUILD -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I create an Entity with javax.persistence annotation, and I create DAO with spring data, a Service and a controller to expose my services.

I add the application.properties in the src/main/resources

```
server.port=1111
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sping-boot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

When i start my application I don't have any error but the database is nit created.

Did I forgot something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get spring boot to automatically create database schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema)

Comment: I think you are right.
I have the main class and the entities in different packages and I have not respected the tree. I will dig in this track if it works I will signal to you.

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` will drop the tables after the application shuts down.

Comment: You aren't using Spring Boot... You are creating a classic war (judging from the plugins you are using) and only use Spring Boot for dependency management. That makes me think those properties are pretty much do nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you add that?

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please add example the EntityScanConfig class.The `@EntityScan` on the other hand does not create beans as far as I know. It only identifies which classes should be used by a specific persistence context

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan({"com.example.entity.model"})
public class EntityScanConfig {

}
```

Comment: I add the main class in the parent package "ma.myapps"
and the rntity in the child package "ma.myapps.entity" and it's working