# java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call and org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, maven

I am trying to connect my Oracle database to my project.And I want to do with hibernate.I am new beginner.But I get this error says `invalid arguments in call`. I have been searching google whole day, but I do not get answer which can solve my problem.Also I have some questions

1) I want to do automatically make my table in oracle by making model class in spring boot.For this I add `persistence.xml` and `application.properties`.Do I really need both this file to make my table automatically with model class in spring?Also I have to mention that my project is web application **not Hibernate**

2)What is benefit of making database with Hibernate?

My `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/java.jdbc -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.data-username=GULSHAN
spring.datasource.data-password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

And my `persistence.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa">

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="gulshan"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pass"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: "Also I have to mention that my project is web application not Hibernate"  didn't get this

Comment: First of all spring boot starter jpa will be sufficient enough to create tables. No need to add Hibernate in your pom. Also, properties file is enough for your needs. Persistence.xml hence not required. Also have a look at this . : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema

Comment: By making project in Hibernate make `persistence.xml`  automatically,but I make `persistence.xml` myself.Also I may understand wrong so I ask questions

Comment: You dont need hibernate when you are using spring boot jpa. Also post the folder structure and files in project. That will be more helpful or better a github link.

Comment: @ Breaking Benjamin Thanks you