# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create is not working in Hibernate 5 with SpringBoot 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

I created a `SpringBoot 1.5.11.RELEASE` and `Hibernate 5 project`. Everything was working fine.

However, when I changed `SpringBoot` version to `2.0.0.RELEASE` the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` does not work. I have tried [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema), but no luck.

Here is the stack trace of `SpringBoot 1.5.11.RELEASE` :

> 2018-04-06 16:27:52.512  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2018-04-06
>   16:27:52.526  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: default   ...] 2018-04-06 16:27:52.587 
>   INFO 6792 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version
>   : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final} 2018-04-06 16:27:52.589 
>   INFO 6792 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>   : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 2018-04-06 16:27:52.591 
>   INFO 6792 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>   : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist 2018-04-06
>   16:27:52.735  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
>   Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2018-04-06 16:27:52.833  INFO 6792
>   --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
>   2018-04-06 16:27:53.180  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl
>   schema export Hibernate: drop table if exists person Hibernate: create
>   table person (id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255),
>   primary key (id)) 2018-04-06 16:27:53.619  INFO 6792 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema
>   export complete 2018-04-06 16:27:53.646  INFO 6792 --- [
>   main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' SessionFactory
>   Created 2018-04-06 16:27:54.528  WARN 6792 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001002: Using
>   Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>   2018-04-06 16:27:54.529  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001005: using driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel]
>   2018-04-06 16:27:54.529  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001001: Connection
>   properties: {user=root, password=****} 2018-04-06 16:27:54.529  INFO
>   6792 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            :
>   HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false 2018-04-06 16:27:54.532  INFO 6792
>   --- [           main] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1) 2018-04-06
>   16:27:54.539  INFO 6792 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 2018-04-06 16:27:54.855  INFO 6792
>   --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup Hibernate: insert into
>   person (name) values (?) Saved!! 2018-04-06 16:27:54.954  INFO 6792
>   --- [           main] com.hib.Hibernate5Application            : Started Hibernate5Application in 4.051 seconds (JVM running for 4.802)

---

Here is the stack trace of `SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE` :

> SessionFactory Created 2018-04-06 16:24:17.011  INFO 5092 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate
>   Core {5.2.14.Final} 2018-04-06 16:24:17.013  INFO 5092 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found 2018-04-06 16:24:17.915  INFO 5092 ---
>   [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   :
>   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2018-04-06
>   16:24:17.989  WARN 5092 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using
>   Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>   2018-04-06 16:24:17.994  INFO 5092 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: using driver
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel]
>   2018-04-06 16:24:17.994  INFO 5092 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection
>   properties: {user=root, password=****} 2018-04-06 16:24:17.994  INFO
>   5092 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    :
>   HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false 2018-04-06 16:24:17.996  INFO 5092
>   --- [           main] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
>
> 2018-04-06 16:24:18.230  INFO 5092 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 2018-04-06 16:24:19.041  INFO 5092
>   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 2018-04-06 16:24:19.058  INFO 5092 --- [
>   main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
>   completed.
>
> 2018-04-06 16:24:19.419  INFO 5092 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX
>   exposure on startup 2018-04-06 16:24:19.420  INFO 5092 --- [
>   main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name
>   'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure 2018-04-06
>   16:24:19.427  INFO 5092 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource':
>   registering with JMX server as MBean
>   [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource] 2018-04-06
>   16:24:19.441  INFO 5092 --- [           main]
>   com.hib.Hibernate5Application            : Started
>   Hibernate5Application in 3.742 seconds (JVM running for 4.541)
>   Hibernate: insert into person (name) values (?) Saved!!

---

`Hibernate 5` configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class HinernateConfig {

    private StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        try {
            standardServiceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sessionFactory =  metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured while creating SessionFactory");
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (standardServiceRegistry != null) {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(standardServiceRegistry);
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void post() {
        System.out.println("SessionFactory Created");
    }

}
```

---

Main application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Application(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Person person = new Person("Mehraj Malik");
        session.save(person);
        System.out.println("Saved!!");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

---

Hibernate Xml config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <mapping class="com.hib.entity.Person"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
application.properties

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

---

In Boot 2.0 stack trace the below part does not appear :

> Running hbm2ddl schema export Hibernate: drop table if exists person
>   Hibernate: create table person (id integer not null auto_increment,
>   name varchar(255), primary key (id))

Github : https://github.com/Mehraj123/Hib5Boot2.0

Comment: but your code is able to run anyways as you are able to save the person also with Spring Boot 2.0.0 as your log file says: `Hibernate5Application in 3.742 seconds (JVM running for 4.541) Hibernate: insert into person (name) values (?) Saved!!`. Have you tried to run your application with Spring Boot 2.0.0 with an empty database?

Comment: You aren't using JPA so why should the `spring.jpa` properties apply. You are configuring your own `SessionFactory` without even as much as using the properties defined in the `application.properties`. Also why use plain hibernate, use JPA and use the `EntityManager` instead, saves you from configuring the `SessionFactory` yourself and you can benefit from the autoconfiguration from Spring Boot.

Comment: @rieckpil yes, it's saving the record to DB, however, it should delete the table and it's data before inserting the new record.

Comment: shouldn't you therefor use `create-drop` for `ddl-auto`?

Comment: @M.Deinum I searched google for hibernate 5 configuration and this the way they have created `SessionFactory` that's why I did in this way. If you have any suggestion or link that would be very helpful.

Comment: @rieckpil nor `create-drop` worked

Comment: Drop the configuration, remove your hibernate configuration and use JPA (with hibernate as the provider).

Comment: @M.Deinum did you mean `application.properties` and `xml configuration`?

Comment: I ment remove your hibernate based configuration class and the hibernate xml configuration. You are using Spring Boot that auto-configures JPA for you... You are making it more complex with trying to do manual configuration (and stil expect auto-configuration to work).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **M.Deinum** I've deleted the following classes and resource file and it works :

- HinernateConfig
- hibernate.cfg.xml

And changes in Main application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Hibernate5Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private EntityManagerFactory managerFactory;

    public Hibernate5Application(EntityManagerFactory managerFactory) {
        this.managerFactory = managerFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Hibernate5Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        EntityManager entityManager = managerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Person person = new Person("Mehraj Malik");
        entityManager.persist(person);
        System.out.println("Saved!!");
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

---

I've updated [my github repo](https://github.com/Mehraj123/Hib5Boot2.0)