# Why spring boot application doesn't generate tables from entity in Postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spring-boot

I have tryed everything what I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema) and in every relevant google match on my searches. I'm stuck with this problem for 2 days now, first I thought the problem might be with MySQL so tried Postgres but still nothing.
The database is connected with the application, when i create a new table i can see in Postgres and if I delete it there it disappears from Intellij also.
But from Entities it generates nothing and doesn't even throw any error.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_demo
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

PostgresDemoApplication clsaa:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@EnableJpaAuditing
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "models")
public class PostgresDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PostgresDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

model class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "question_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "question_generator",
            sequenceName = "question_generator",
            initialValue = 1000
    )
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;
```

Spring boot

```
2018-09-09 14:11:35.261  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.p.PostgresDemoApplication            : Starting PostgresDemoApplication on DESKTOP-5Q2LCCO with PID 2140 (D:\Isshae\Java\postgres-demo\out\production\classes started by asus in D:\Isshae\Java\postgres-demo)
2018-09-09 14:11:35.262  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.p.PostgresDemoApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-09 14:11:35.338  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@44c035dd: startup date [Sun Sep 09 14:11:35 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-09 14:11:36.467  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41d31d19] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-09-09 14:11:36.908  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-09-09 14:11:36.925  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-09-09 14:11:36.925  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-09-09 14:11:36.929  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.052  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-09 14:11:37.052  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1717 ms
2018-09-09 14:11:37.111  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.111  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.111  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.111  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.111  INFO 2140 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.242  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-09-09 14:11:37.498  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-09-09 14:11:37.534  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-09 14:11:37.534  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-09-09 14:11:37.675  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-09-09 14:11:37.677  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-09-09 14:11:37.707  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-09-09 14:11:37.809  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-09-09 14:11:37.829  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2018-09-09 14:11:37.829  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4ab9bbe7
2018-09-09 14:11:38.554  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@7d8c0ef6'
2018-09-09 14:11:38.554  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-09 14:11:38.724  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-09 14:11:38.974  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@44c035dd: startup date [Sun Sep 09 14:11:35 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-09 14:11:38.999  WARN 2140 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-09-09 14:11:39.052  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-09-09 14:11:39.053  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-09-09 14:11:39.076  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-09 14:11:39.076  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-09 14:11:39.123  WARN 2140 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2018-09-09 14:11:39.371  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-09-09 14:11:39.394  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-09-09 14:11:39.399  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-09-09 14:11:39.403  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-09-09 14:11:39.435  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-09-09 14:11:39.436  INFO 2140 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.p.PostgresDemoApplication            : Started PostgresDemoApplication in 4.503 seconds (JVM running for 5.399)
```

Comment: Why do you use EntityScan? Are your entities not bellow the SpringBootApplication?

Comment: Entities are in a different package but it doesn't matter, its not working with the scan neather without.

Comment: Can you try with update?

Comment: Done it already, and every other basic solution and variation on the matter.

Comment: can you remove spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true and try again. and also remove spaces before or after the = symbol

Comment: Tried that too :) and nothing

Comment: @EntityScan(basePackages = "models") are the entities really in that package? there is no package structure like. x.y.models?

Comment: Ok i have updated the @Entity scan to com.x. models, still not working. Re-installed intellij and mysql(also changed all the properties and dependencies) nothing has changed. I'm stuck with this problem and have no idea WTF is wrong with it.