# Auto database creation springboot and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-boot

I am trying create mysql database when application starts up. I have tried with bellow configuration but could not able to achieve, Please let me know if anybody have idea about this,

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like creating schema automatically if not exists?

Comment: Please use below link for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for to create database if not exists then you can use below in database configuration file.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Otherwise make sure you have below properties in your application properties file.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the property with a value that actually creates the schema, for instance:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

You may find a more detailed reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following option:

```
"createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"DB_NAME"?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```