# Can't see MYSQL table information in MYSQL workbench, spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to connect my spring boot app to MYSQL workbench but I can't find any of my columns in MYSQL WorkBench.

My set up:
This application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When I try without "?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC" I get the following error

```
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

My Maven dependencies

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.blogportfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Bala's Blog</name>
    <description>Blog portfolio backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The Article Class

```
package com.blogbackend.Model;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table (name = "Articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="articleName")
    private String artName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="articleBody")
    private String artBody;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="articleCategory")
    private String artCategory;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="articleCreated")
    private Date artCreated;

    @Column
    private Author author;

    public Article(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When I go to the WorkBench the Blog schema is empty.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it has nothing to do with the schema/table you want to use but is more a server configuration issue. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) it comes with a certain version of the used driver, that it's mandatory to set this property.

In order to accomplish the automatic creation of the desired tables, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema) might help.

If the creation is already successful while the application is running, just change the `ddl-auto` paramter from

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

and once created change to `validate` or `update`

Further explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha).

Comment: Hi Ben, I updated my question w/ my Maven dependencies. Which one should I change and try again? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you had to go back quite some versions. I'd recommend sticking with the latest version you can and add the property with the desired timezone that fits your setup.

Comment: Ah I think i just got your question. Try adding the property to the jdbc connection string, start your app and while it is running can you check it in workbench?

Comment: In case it is not working, you should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema

Comment: In case you see the expected tables: change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop ` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` and once created change to `validate` or update

Comment: I tried this and nothing has changed, should I use a different MYSql database. I am using MySQLWorkBench right now.

Comment: If the application does not create the tables check the second link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your identity generation strategy for `Article` entity is `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. But `MySQL` doesn't support `Sequence` directly.

That it why if fails when `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` is trying to create a schema.

Use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) instead with `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.