# Spring Boot with JPA does not generate tables in the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When I run the project, does not create tables in MySQL.

I tried to change the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` to create-drop and also does not to create.

No error appears in the log.

My class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity(name = "tb_user")
public class User {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Column(length = 75, nullable = false)
 private String name;

 @Column(length = 75, nullable = false, unique = true)
 private String email;

 @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
 private String password;
 }
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db_spring?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=1234567
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Have you tried solutions in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I think you're probably missing the hibernate dialect?

Comment: first, you should create your database yourselff.

Comment: my dialect is configured and my database created, but no error message appears in my log

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

also check you are using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and entity classes are in same package or subpackage

Comment: I tried to add `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`, but it still doesn't work and the annotations are right