# Creating tables in database with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, web

There is a web application using Spring Boot and JpaRepository interface to perform database queries. I want the application to be able to create tables in the database on its own at startup. How can this be done? Maybe I need to use Hibernate or something else for this? without xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JPA configurations to your application.properties file. Example of MySQL is below:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=
```

you can see some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema).
Also, read about spring boot and JPA [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Liquibase with Spring Boot (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup)). It will be possible to create and update your database tables at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to use MySQL use the previous answer and if needed to use postgres then use the code given below.

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schema_name
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```