Table is not getting automatically created when running a spring-boot application with gradle
I have a springboot application that I am running with gradle. I have a mysql container running on docker which I am using as my database. When I run gradlew bootRun, the application starts but my 'users' table is not created in my 'sqldb' database.
Here is my application.properties:
spring.application.name=API
server.port=8005

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/sqldb?serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=YES

## Hibernate properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

And my application.java:
package com.rest.API;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

and my 'users' entity:
package com.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import java.util.Date;

@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "CreationTime")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "UpdationTime")
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}

And finally the output in my terminal when I run gradlew bootRun:
2024-12-26T15:20:38.652+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] com.rest.API.Application                 : Starting Application using Java 17.0.13 with PID 15824 (C:\Users\ukumar\Documents\SecureCRUDAPI\API\build\classes\java\main started by ukumar in C:\Users\ukumar\Documents\SecureCRUDAPI\API)
2024-12-26T15:20:38.656+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] com.rest.API.Application                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-12-26T15:20:39.572+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode
2024-12-26T15:20:39.601+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-12-26T15:20:40.551+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8005 (http)
2024-12-26T15:20:40.567+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-12-26T15:20:40.568+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.33]
2024-12-26T15:20:40.701+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-26T15:20:40.704+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1976 ms
2024-12-26T15:20:40.936+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-12-26T15:20:41.054+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.6.2.Final
2024-12-26T15:20:41.124+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-12-26T15:20:41.678+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-12-26T15:20:41.736+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-12-26T15:20:42.071+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@bb6f3f7
2024-12-26T15:20:42.074+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-12-26T15:20:42.212+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: Database info:
        Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
        Database driver: undefined/unknown
        Database version: 9.1
        Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
        Isolation level: undefined/unknown
        Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
        Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown
2024-12-26T15:20:42.763+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-12-26T15:20:42.776+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-12-26T15:20:43.336+05:30  WARN 15824 --- [API] [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: c2a9627b-8216-425c-961a-9777f98631e7

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2024-12-26T15:20:43.373+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] r$InitializeUserDetailsManagerConfigurer : Global AuthenticationManager configured with UserDetailsService bean with name inMemoryUserDetailsManager
2024-12-26T15:20:43.668+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8005 (http) with context path '/'
2024-12-26T15:20:43.679+05:30  INFO 15824 --- [API] [           main] com.rest.API.Application                 : Started Application in 5.651 seconds (process running for 6.33)
<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [38s]


Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema answer your question?

Your main class and entities are not in same base package, by default hibernate will only scan for entities in base package of main, to solve this you can move your entity to same base package as main class or add following annoatation on your main class Your main class and entities are not in same base package, by default hibernate will only scan for entities in base package of main, to solve this you can move your entity to same base package as main class or add following:
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.entities")

@kushparsaniya
thanks a lot. It worked

@MarioMateaș
No, it did not. I had already looked into that question
